# How to apply the same background animation on multiple child elements?

Tags: css, animation, overlay, opacity

I would like to know what is the better approach to making several elements to use the same animated background, as shown in the picture above. For sure, it is possible to calculate the animated gradient independently for each element, but I would like to have a general solution since a number of children and their position could be different.

[image: Explanation]

```
<div class = 'parent'>
  <div class = 'child child-header'>Child 1</div>
  <div class = 'child child-column'>Child 2</div>
  <div class = 'child child-column'>Child 3</div>
  <div class = 'child child-column'>Child 4</div>
</div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#d8d8d8,#bdbdbd,#d8d8d8);
  animation: skeleton-shimmer 2.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.child-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-column {
  width: 33%;
}

@keyframes skeleton-shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -200px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: calc(200px + 100%) 0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zarfbgw/

What I would like to achieve here is to make all children use a single animation effect (children could have different positions).

Comment: Have your tried percentages? Put the code you have so far into your question - at the moment we can't fully understand what you mean and any answer will just be a guess.

Comment: background-attachment: fixed

Comment: What is it that is wrong with the effects that you have? Is it the timing?

Comment: @AHaworth I specifically make this wrong in the example. For sure, I could calculate animation for each independent child. But I would like to understand, is it possible to do this without adjusting child elements. All children elements could move dynamically.

So, strictly speaking, - is it possible to make a middle layer transparent for child elements (look at the picture)?

Comment: So you ust want one background (animated) for the whole viewport (or the whole page?).

Comment: @AHaworth I would like to make any child to use the same background (animated). The space between those children elements should be filled by some color (middle layer in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the moving background to each of the children's before pseudo element - that pseudo element covering the whole parent.

This snippet puts a clip path on each of the children so the 'excess' background on the pseudo element isn't seen. For the purposes of demonstration it also spaces them out a bit and puts a black background color on the parent so the difference in the two backgrounds can be seen.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10vmin;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.child {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.child::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #d8d8d8, #bdbdbd, #d8d8d8);
  animation: skeleton-shimmer 2.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.child-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-column {
  width: 33%;
}

@keyframes skeleton-shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -200px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: calc(200px + 100%) 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child child-header'>Child 1</div>
  <div class='child child-column'>Child 2</div>
  <div class='child child-column'>Child 3</div>
  <div class='child child-column'>Child 4</div>
</div>
```